# Change permissions in elastic beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created a php website using laravel and used elastic beanstalk for hosting. Now I'm trying to change permissions of some folders of my project but couldn't find a way to do it through console.
PS: I'm new to AWS.

Comment: please add some detail to this question and make sure it is not answered elsewhere on stack overflow. it might be helpful to know what you've tried, what some details of your deployment are, which console you're talking about. please also edit your question title to be in the form of a question, usually starting with a question word (how/why/what) and ending in a question mark. welcome to s/o and thank you for your question!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this through console. Instead you can do this using [plaform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

For example you could setup `postdeploy` deployment hook in your source code. The hook would use bash commands to modify the permissions of the folders you require.

The other possibility would be using [container commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) in `.ebextentions`.